firebase apps:create android store_app (android) --package-name=ashu --json --project=storeapp-33838, when run this command it's faild to create app
I try to connect my flutter project with firebase with everything fine but at the end process there is an error occured "FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android store_app (android) --package-name=ashu --json --project=storeapp-33838
ERROR: Failed to create Android app for project storeapp-33838. See firebase-debug.log for more info."
and I didn't understand it , I try but faild again and again,
I try by finding solution by blackbox but there is no any particular solution that i try and I'm a fresher to this firebase that also cause problem
